# Regular expression in PHP being too greedy on words

Tags: php, regex

I know I'm just being simple-minded at this point but I'm stumped. Suppose I have a textual target that looks like this:

**Johnny was really named for his 1234 grandfather, John Hugenot, but his T5677 id was JH6781 and his little brother's HG766 id was RB1223.**

Using this RegExp: `\s[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d\d\s`, how would I extract, individually, the first and second occurrences of the matching strings? "JH6781" and "RB1223", respectively. I guarantee that the matching string will appear exactly twice in the target text.

Note: I do NOT want to change the existing string at all, so `str_replace()` is not an option.

Comment: So you always want to extract the second and fourth `[A-Z][A-Z]\d{4}`?

Answer (score 4):

Erm... how about using this regex:

```
/\b[A-Z]{2}\d{4}\b/
```

It means 'match boundary of a word, followed by exactly two capital English letters, followed by exactly four digits, followed by a word boundary'. So it won't match 'TGX7777' (word boundary is followed by three letters - pattern match failed), and it won't match 'TX77777' (four digits are followed by another digit - fail again).

And that's how it can be used:

```
$str = "Johnny was really named for his 1234 grandfather, John Hugenot, but his T5677 id was JH6781 and his little brother's HG766 id was RB1223.";

preg_match_all('/\b[A-Z]{2}\d{4}\b/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]); 
// array
//  0 => string 'JH6781' (length=6)
//  1 => string 'RB1223' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$s='Johnny was really named for his 1234 grandfather, John Hugenot, but his T5677 id was JH6781 and his little brother\'s HG766 id was RB1223.';
$n=preg_match_all('/\b[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d\d\b/',$s,$m);
```

gives the result `$n=2`, then

```
print_r($m);
```

gives the result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => JH6781
            [1] => RB1223
        )
)
```

Comment: Love it, thanks! Took a little bit of each answer and came up with '\b[A-Z]{2}\d{4}\b' using the `preg_match_all()`. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `preg_match` with the offset parameter(5th) and `strpos` to select the first and second occurrence.
Alternatively you could use `preg_match_all` and just use the first two array entries

```php
<?php
$first = preg_match($regex, $subject, $match);
$second = preg_match($regex, $subject, $match, 0, strpos($match[0]) + 1);
?>
```